# Logging Data via Docker Logs - .NET Core 3.1 Filebeat ELK

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, filebeat, elk

I am using Docker logs with the standard driver to show dummy data from a .Net Core web app via `docker logs [options]`

More specifically, I am using `ILogger<>`

`logger.LogDebug("Hello from web app");`

The output is:

```
2020-02-03T15:29:02.378269378Z dbug: WebAppLogger.Startup[0]
2020-02-03T15:29:02.378353836Z       Hello from Configure
```

Eventually I want to use `Filebeat` in conjunction with `ELK` to send these logs to, but the examples I have found are more like this:

`11/June/2019:00:10:45 + 0000 DEBUG "This is a generic log message example"`

Mine seems to go onto 2 lines with two slightly different times (milliseconds). Is there a more apt logging library for this, or is it something I am doing wrong?